# Style HTML5 in IE without js

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

please is there a way how to apply styles to html5 elements like header, section, aside etc. in older IEs, but without using javascript?
I know that there is the `document.createElement(elem);` solution, but is that possible even withou scripts?

Comment: The minimal thing you can do is set `display: block` on the HTML5 elements but it won't solve the problem and there is no real solution without javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This isn't possible* because the default behavior of older Internet Explorer versions is to ignore any not known element. This is why we use the JavaScript approach to "create" elements so that the browser recognizes them.

However, I don't believe that relying on JavaScript is a bad thing, after all there is virtually no user currently with JavaScript off. And if it happens, your site will not be the only one with problems.

Also, you don't need to write all those scripts by yourself. You can rely on something like the [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) that does it all for you (and some other things).

However, you can also use approaches to: redirect the user to another page depending on the version of the browser (with server coding), or that use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to write only known tags on IE.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice fix available that introduces a namespace:

http://debeterevormgever.nl/en/articles/html5-elements-ie-without-javascript

Works well in IE7, IE8.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest if you're that concerned about supporting users with older versions of Internet Explorer without resorting to JavaScript, then HTML5 isn't for you (in this project anyway) and I'd suggest sticking with HTML 4.01.

Always choose the right tools for the job.

Comment: thats exactly how I am doing..but people want everything..they need having cool websites with html5 elements and on the other hand they want site displaying even on dummy calculator:)

Answer (score 0):

First check, then try to help!
1. You can make your own namespace
2. You can use [if ie] in HTML. If it's IE then use div if it's not then use html5 tag. See on Google for this one.
If it's important for you see this article:
http://debeterevormgever.nl/en/articles/html5-elements-ie-without-javascript